# Java working with files

Tags: java, file, input, output

I have just started today to learn java. I am usually using C++ for school but now I want to learn more programming languages.

In C++ when I am using file inputs or outputs, I create them in the project directory.

OK, first question. When I am coding algorithmic problems in C++, I usually have to use file inputs & outputs. [I created the files like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab1TE.png)

Is it the correct way to do it? In C++, if I created the files in the project directory, I do not have to write any directories, only the file names.

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class kMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new FileReader("file_input.in"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(
                            new BufferedWriter(
                                    new FileWriter("file_output.out")));
        br.close();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file_input.in (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at kMax.main(kMax.java:6)
```

Comment: Does the file `graf_partial.in` or `file_input.in` (as shown in your error log) exist? Why can't you just read and understand the error log? They're all in English.

Comment: Also... [NO "I am new to" please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Edited, the file names in the code were wrong, I forgot to change them. Same error log.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is: *"file_input.in (The system cannot find the file specified)"*.  You have got the file name wrong.  There is no `file_input.in` file in the application's current directory.

Comment: does your code know where to find the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The File class have a constructor method:

```
File(String path)
```

If the path start with a drive,like

```
String path = "D:/newFile.txt";
```

the file path will be considered as an absolute path.
If the path not start with a driva, like:

```
String path1 = "newFile.txt";
```

It will be considered as a relative path, which relative to the project.
So, your file should be create in the project "Test".
Like this:

[The file to java File class look for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUUkA.png)

Comment: Relative path will relative to the current work path,which can got by    System.getProperty("user.dir");

Answer (score 0):

Its important to know where Java class will look for file.

just add this line

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

You will get working directory, Add your files in this path.

And if you are using any IDE like eclipse or netbeans
Just add your files in project folder (*FYI for eclipse project folder is working folder*)